# InvalidParameterException while confirming SNS notification using Java spring cloud aws

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, spring-cloud

I have SNS http end point written using Spring-aws-cloud. I followed the below [tutorial](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_http_notification_endpoint). While I request confirmation from my SNS topic I get the following error from my application console. Seems the status.confirmSubscription() is failing. 
Error I am getting is :

```
zonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: d47581bd-789f-58f0-b976-ced91fec6929)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2459) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.10.7.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.confirmSubscription(AmazonSNSClient.java:284) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.10.7.jar:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.confirmSubscription(AmazonSNSClient.java:1761) ~[aws-java-sdk-sns-1.10.7.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.endpoint.NotificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver$AmazonSnsNotificationStatus.confirmSubscription(NotificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:62) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
        at com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.controller.SNSController.handleSubscriptionMessage(SNSController.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

My pom.xml is as below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.fastretailing.fr-cpf-scm-producer</groupId>
      <artifactId>fr-cpf-scm-producer</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
      </parent>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring cloud for SNS http endpoint-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Spring AWS autoconfiguration-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache commons-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Amazon s3 client-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
          <version> 1.10.61</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mongo client -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.0.1</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-version>
      </properties>


      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>config</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: I would like to add some clarification because I had the same problem. The problem was the TopicARN being URLEncoded in the subscription confirmation message. After stumbling across this post I noticed my subscription confirmation was being sent to a us-east URL. After explicitly setting the region I was able to subscribe no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed. Issue was with the region configuration. For Spring aws cloud we have to disable auto detection of region and need to configure the desired one.

Comment: AWS is notoriously known throwing random errors just because somewhere region was not set. E.g. in a SNS subscription where it's apparently not enough to provide SNS topic arn containing region, one also needs to provide it separately.

Answer (score 7):

Like Bill says, need to configure the region. Here's some sample code:

```
return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
        .build();
```

For more information, see

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/creating-clients.html

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue and I have refer the this [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=478775). 
In fact the my issue was : **Topic/Target arn is for `us-west-2`. But but default my SNS client is pointing to** `ap-southeast-1`

In fact this [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=478775) tell the same:

Topic/Target arn is for us-west-2. But but default your SNS client is pointing to **us-east-1**. You need to call setRegion on snsClient like this: snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(**Regions.US_WEST_2**));

It may help some one.